# Three.js set face color

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to set the color of a face but failed. If I use `wireframe`, the result seems to be correct. But if not, the face seems not to be rendered.

```
var geo = new THREE.Geometry();
geo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 0));
geo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0));
geo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
geo.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));
geo.faces[0].color = new THREE.Color('rgb(0,255,0)');
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
    color: 0xff0000//,
    //wireframe: true
}));
scene.add(mesh);
```

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yaxpberz/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that according to the vertex order when added to face, the camera is looking at the back side of the mesh. So, it can be solved by:

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
    color: 0xff0000,
    side: THREE.BackSide
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your vertices in a clockwise manner. You should be adding them counter-clockwise. Switch the first and third vertices. That way you can avoid the performance overhead of drawing a face twice.